# Eclipse's "serve modules without publishing" equivalent in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I checked the "serve modules without publishing" in eclipse,eclipse would add all of my maven dependencies to context xml like

And the tomcat would run with adding this jars to command line classpath.
But in Idea,I set deployment to exploded,all of my maven dependencies were copided to output/WEB-INF/lib
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKyLA.png)

How can i acheive running tomcat without coping maven dependencies?